# Javascript DOM clarification

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm learning how to appending DOM nodes with Javascript and have a little clarification question. Here's an example:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>

    document.childNodes[0]
```

So here, you would get the `<head>` node because it is the first child after the `<html>` tag. My question is can I always consider "document" to be the equivalent of the `<html>` tag or root node?

Comment: it depends on your context/environment - it will always be the document by default in the browser, but javascript can run in other environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend studying [the W3C DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/) as well: even if some parts of it won't mean much to you, it might save you a plenty of time and efforts later. )

That's what's said about `document` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#i-Document):

> The Document interface represents the entire HTML or XML document.
>   Conceptually, it is the root of the document tree, and provides the
>   primary access to the document's data.

Answer (score 0):

`document.childNodes[0]` is the `<!DOCTYPE>` node when I try it (though not sure if that's always the case).

`document.documentElement` is the `<html>` tag.

`document.body` is the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Root node for html is ... html, which can be get via `document.documentElement`

I'm not sure, it is supported in all modern browsers, though.

Answer (score 0):

`document.childNodes[0]` will be the html tag in your example.